# permutation transposition proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

Let v be a permutation of n elements such that $v^2$ is the identity.

Prove that $v$ is a product of disjoint transpositions.

My thinking: $v^2$ is the identity so intuivitly I can see why it is true. Since after $V$ is applied, you have then have to do the exact opposite to get by the identity element. (by applying $V$), which implies a product of disjoint transpositions.

But how would I go about an actual proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutation $v$ can have only cycles of length $1$ or $2$, otherwise the order of the permutation is larger than $2$, so $v^2$ cannot be the identical permutation.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand. Are you doing a proof by contradiction?

Comment: The order of an element $a$ in a group is the smallest positive integer $o$ with $a^o=e$. If a permutation $p$ has a cycle of length $n$  , $o$ must be at least $n$ because the permutations $p,p^2,\cdots,p^{n-1}$ all have a cycle of length $n$. So, yes , my proof is a contradiction-proof.

Comment: So the logic is: The order of v is the lcm of the length of it's cycles. Since the order of v is 2, the cycles must be of length 1 or 2. But isn't a transposition a 2 cycle? So are 1 cycles just considered trivial?

Comment: Yes, exactly that !

Comment: sorry I edited. Can you read again please

Comment: I noticed it and you are right. Transpositions are $2$-cycles and $1$-cycles fixpoints (you can also call them trivial cycles).